# Is it possible to clean ubuntu server after sending response?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, virtual-machine, reset

I wanted to ask if is it possible to clean ubuntu server after sending response to webpage and restore it to default settings (I mean deleting all files and changes made by user.)? Because I want to send some bash script via form to ubuntu server and later execute it and return some response on webpage. But if this bash script will be creating some files or changing anything on server, I want to clean it after resposne will be send on page. Is it possible in anyway? Somebody have any idea how can I do it or what will be usefull to do it? I wanted just to create ubuntu server on VM but maybe somebody have better ideas what will be more useful to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the machine is a VM, the easiest solution is to take a snapshot and roll it back after running the script.

But an untrusted script could also change things on the network as well as on the machine, so you'll need to isolate the machine or trust the script.